# Getting the recipient view with existing envelope and template

Tags: docusignapi

So I've "sent" my envelope created from a template which has a workflow in it. Now I want to give my recipients the opportunity to pull up the documents and review and sign them... unfortunately every thing I'm reading wants you to create another envelope. How do I go about having a button ready for when my user logs into my portal they can hit it and go to the signers view and start signing the documents I had uploaded and tagged in the envelope I had created previously ?

Answer (score 2):

`Embedded Signing` is what you're looking for. Here are some links that will help you getting started:

[API - Embedding](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign)

[Embedded Signing](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/embedded-signing)

[Embedded Signing Walkthrough](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedSigning)